# jQuery TableTools buttons not loading

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I am trying to add `tableTools` to an existing table that already uses the `DataTable` plug in. The `tableTools` buttons do not load. This is my code:

```
var dataTableOptions = {
  "sScrollY":   "475px",
  "bAutoWidth": true,
  "bSort":      true,
  "bPaginate":  true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "bFilter":    true,
  "bInfo":      true,
  "bJQueryUI":  true,
  "sDom": '<"clear">lfrtip',
  "oTableTools": {"sSwfPath": appPath + "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"}
};

$j("#movementsResults table").dataTable(dataTableOptions);
```

The `dataTable` part works fully, but `tableTools` don't seem to be working. I have ensured all file paths are correct, including the `.swf` path and I just can't find the problem.

Comment: Isn't your sDom supposed to have an upper case "T" for the tools?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I'm not sure, but I just tried it and it made DataTables stop working completely (I get a basic html table)

Comment: Did you get any errors in your console when it stopped working?

Comment: @MikeRobinson `SCRIPT5009: 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools' is undefined 
TableTools.js, line 1293 character 3` that line of code is `var flash = new ZeroClipboard_TableTools.Client();`

Comment: @MikeRobinson After googling, I realised I need to include ZeroClipboard.js, having done so the buttons now come up. Will work on the styling and functionality (as they don't actually work at the minute) of them and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running developer tools I got an error:

SCRIPT5009: 'ZeroClipboard_TableTools' is undefined TableTools.js, line 1293 character 3

After googling to find out exactly what ZeroClipboard was, I found out I needed to include that JS file separately, as it was trying to call a function that was created in there. After doing so the buttons started to work, just a matter of styling them now.

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
"sDom": 'Tlfrtip'
```

also, have you verified the appPath variable to be correct?  Maybe add this to your code and check the console to verify you dont have like an extra slash or something:

```
console.log(appPath + "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf");
```

Comment: The issue was ZeroClipboard.js but that sDom does style it better

Answer (score 0):

It's required to initialise it in the sDom with T:
 "sDom": '<"clear">lfrtipT',

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [ZeroClipboard.js](https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/blob/master/src/ZeroClipboard.js) from the DataTables/DataTools project, not the one from the ZeroClipboard project.  They are very different.